# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'CakeTestSuite' not found in

Tags: php, cakephp, phpunit, cakephp-2.x

I'm new to PHP and I got existing CakePHP project but I cannot start it from PHP Storm. Every time I want to run app it shows error:

> PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'CakeTestSuite' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\dummy\dummy_app\Plugin\AclExtras\Test\Case\AllTestsTest.php:16

`AllTestsTest.php` file:

```
require_once 'PHPUnit/Autoload.php';

class AllTestsTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite {


    public static function suite() {
        $suite = new CakeTestSuite('All Tests');
        $suite->addTestDirectoryRecursive(App::pluginPath('AclExtras') . 'Test' . DS . 'Case' . DS);

        return $suite;
    }
}
```

Error is set to: `$suite = new CakeTestSuite('All Tests');`

Any ideas why or how to fix this?

Comment: The most common reason fr that error is that the class you try to instantiate hasn't been included. Try to `include()`  or `require()` the file that contains the class if you haven't yet.

Comment: Thank you @ksjohn

Comment: or could include the namespace `Path\File\CakeTestSuite`

Answer (score 0):

CakePHP 2.x testsuites cannot be run directly via PHPUnit, it requires CakePHPs custom autoloader and uses a custom test runner. You have to use the CakePHP test shell instead.

```
./Console/cake test AclExtras
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Development > Testing](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/testing.html#running-tests-from-command-line)**
- **[Cookbook > Development > Testing > Running tests from command line](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/testing.html)**

Comment: I fixed my problem but this is very usefull, thanks :)